# How to use React HOC for authenticated routing?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I'm trying to add private routing to my app, but I get this error:

> Invariant failed: You should not use `<Route>` outside a
> `<Router>`

Here is my code:

App.js:

```js
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Route render={({ history }) => (
                    <div className="App">
                        <Navbar history={history} />
                        <Switch>
                            <Auth path="/" component={HomePage} currUser={this.props.currUser} />
                            <Route path="/login" render={(props) => (<LoginPage {...props} login={this.props.login} />)} />
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                )} />
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

const Auth = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    const {currUser} = rest;
    return (
        <Route {...rest} render=
            {props =>
                currUser ?
                    (<Component {...props} currUser={currUser.name} />) :
                    (<Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login", state: currUser }} />)
            } />
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        currUser: state.auth.currUser
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    ...authActions,
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Auth);
```

What am I doing wrong?
And how do I pass props from the `Redux` state to the components in this method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrapped the `Auth` component with the `App` component, so your file should export the `App`. When you export only the `Auth`, the `<Route>` tag in `Auth` is outside the router tag.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: It works, thank you!
But how do I pass the props to the components from the state? (:

Comment: You can put the `Auth` component in another file and connect it too. More easy way is to propagate your props like that: store -> `App` -> `Auth`.